# Is the Hasse diagram of $(X,\mid)$ a tree?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $X=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and let $(X,\mid)$ be a poset with the the partial order of divisibility on $X$. Is the directed Hasse diagram of $(X,\mid)$ a directed rooted tree?
(Where the arrows points from $a$ to $b$ off $b$ covers $a$)
Proving that it's a directed rooted tree will also prove the well known fact that every common divisor of two numbers divides their gcd.
But, I couldn't give any proof to this problem other than using the above fact and reversing the arguments. I am searching for another proof which doesn't use the above fact.

Comment: Why would it be a tree? Have you tried drawing it for, say, $n=6$ to see if it looks like a tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a tree as soon as $X$ contains a number of the form $pq$ with $p\neq q$: $$1\to p\to pq\to q\to 1$$ will be a loop.

**After edit:** note that for a directed graph, being a tree and not having oriented loops are two different things. A directed graph is a tree if and only if the underlying undirected graph is a tree. In fact, a tree is most of the time defined as an **undirected** graph with no loops.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention that the graph is directed. I am very sorry for that. Fixing it.

Comment: @himanshumallick A tree is not directed.